# How can this behaviour using a Hibernate query be explained? Is it due to Hibernate lazyness?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm, lazy-loading

This morning, I ran into a behaviour i can not really explain : when trying to save (or retrieve if it already exists) some objects with the help of GORM, i was surprised by a `NullPointerException` when a object (with name "name3") is simply retrieved from the db and stored in a `List` and read as `null` afterwards. What surprised me is when i stored this object in a `def` variable (or whatever is not a collection, i guess), the exception disappear.

Here is a sample code (the database is empty at the beginning, by the way)

```
// A simple domain class : 
class MyDomainClass {
    String name
}


//In the PluginClass where i initialize some pieces of data : 
def doWithApplicationContext = { ctx ->

    MyDomainClass.withNewSession {

        def myDomainObjectsNames = ["name1","name2"]
        def myDomainObjectsList = []
        myDomainObjectsNames.each { name ->
            def myDomainObject = MyDomainClass.findByName(name) ?: new MyDomainClass(name: name).save(failOnError: true)
            myDomainObjectsList.add(myDomainObject)
        }
        myDomainObjectsList.each { println("object : " + it.toString())}

        myDomainObjectsNames = ["name3","name2"]
        myDomainObjectsList = []
        myDomainObjectsNames.each { name ->
            myDomainObjectsList << MyDomainClass.findByName(name) ?: new MyDomainClass(name: name).save(failOnError: true)
        }
        myDomainObjectsList.each { println("object : " + it.toString())}
    }
}
```

Code output :

```
object : mypackage.MyDomainClass : 1
object : mypackage.MyDomainClass : 2
object : null // Can't explain
object : mypackage.MyDomainClass : 2
```

Could it be due to Hibernate lazyness? Or Groovy dynamic typing ? I'm not sure.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not about the local variable, but the [precendence of `<<` vs `?:`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_operator_precedence).  Your second loop there adds the result of the `findBy` to the list first.

```
def list = []
list << null ?: 666
assert list.first()==null
```

Comment: also each time you use `each` to `collect` a kitten dies

Comment: Oh, i feel so mad now. Of course, your are right. It was so simple after all. Thank you very much. I will see what i can do for these kitten too.

Comment: Using `collect` is the right way to do this. But now, i know  that i have to care more about operator precendence! Thanks again.